# Change Checkbox Checked Value based upon variable passed by href

Tags: javascript, checkbox, parameter-passing

Using Javascript and HTML Form

Page 1: Simple Link passing two variables (page1var1=xxxx and page1var=yyyy) separated by an "&" symbol

Page 2: Use Javascript to "split" the two variables either side of the "&" into page2var1 and page2var2

So now `page2var1=xxxx` and `page2var2=yyyy` (successfully done already)

How do I use these variables in page 2 to:

1. Check a form input checkbox (i.e. "put a tick in the box") which has the ID/Name) Page2var1 (i.e. xxxx)
2. Put the variable page2var2 (i.e. yyyy) into the value of a fixed form textarea

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
document.GetElementById(Page2var1).checked = true;
document.GetElementById(page2var2).value = 'whatever text'
```

Nothing google wouldn't help you with.

Comment: I want to post a reply but I keep running out of letters!  How do I reply to you in full?

Comment: I have -751 characters left when I put my real reply in = how do I get arounf this?

Comment: I think part 2 is supposed to be: `document.getElementById(textAreaID).value = page2var2;`