# Change value of checkbox based on value of other form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to have a checkbox called 'All' that when checked, also checks the rest of the checkboxes in my form.  I have basically no javascript experience so sorry if this is really basic.  I patched this together from looking at posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539139/change-get-check-state-of-checkbox) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810182/change-checkbox-checked-value-based-upon-variable-passed-by-href).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkIt(checkbox)
{
  document.GetElementById("1").checked = true;
  document.GetElementById("2").click();

}
</script>
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="A" onclick="checkIt(this)">All<br></input>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1">One<br></input>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2">Two<br></input>
</form>
```

How can I get checkboxes 1 and 2 to change when I select checkbox All?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes thats exactly what i need.  Failure on my internet searching skills.  Posting here always makes me feel like an idiot.

Comment: Dude, don't sweat it all! Just stay after it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you are not familiar with javascript, I suggest looking into the jQuery javascript library. Many coders find it simpler to learn/use, and there is no debate that it requires MUCH less typing.

[Here are some introductory jQuery tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32) if you are curious.

To solve your problem, I added a class to the checkboxes that you wish to automatically check/uncheck, and used that class to check/uncheck the boxes.

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/K79mg/)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="A">All<br></input>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" id="1">One<br></input>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" id="2">Two<br></input>
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#A').click(function() {
   // alert($(this).prop('checked'));
    if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
        $('.cb').prop('checked', true);
    }else{
        $('.cb').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Note that this solution uses jQuery, so you need the jQuery library loaded (usually put this line in your head tags):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent answer to a different question.